# Deleting Columns from a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I know similar questions to this have been asked, but I couldn't find any that were dealing with the error I'm getting (though I apologize if I'm missing something!). I am trying to remove a few columns from a CSV that wouldn't load in Excel so I couldn't just delete them within the file. I have the following code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Project\North American Breeding Bird Survey")
data = pd.read_csv("NABBSStateData.csv")
data.drop(["CountryNum", "Route", "RPID"], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

but when I run it I get this error message:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\professional\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py:1664: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  return self._exec(is_module, entry_point_fn, module_name, file, globals, locals)
```

I am relatively new to python/visual studio, and I am having a hard time figuring out what this error message is saying and how to fix it. Thank you!!

Edit: The CSV in question is the state files from [this](ftp://ftpext.usgs.gov/pub/er/md/laurel/BBS/DataFiles/States/) site concatenated together, so you can open one of the state files to see the columns/data types.

Comment: What is the version of you are using?

Comment: I am using python 3.7!

Comment: can you share your csv file in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have mixed data types in some of your columns (e.g. columns 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13). 
Mixed data type means in one column, say column 'a', most rows are numbers, but there might be strings in some rows as well.

Try use `dtype` option from `pd.read_csv` to specify the column types. If you are not sure about the type, use `object` or `str`.
This is an example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\foo.csv', header=0, dtype={'currency':str, 'v1':object, 'v2':object})
```

[A link to use read_csv](https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read_csv-load-data-from-csv-files/)

[Here's list of all the types you can specify](https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html).

Comment: I tried using that code and defining all my columns as object and str, but got the same error for both. I also tried defining them as int, but I got the exception unhandled error ```invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'RouteDataID'``` before I could run the program. Do you know why this might be? Thanks!!